# Conditional Independence of Gaussian processes

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that we have $g_{1}(t),\ldots,g_{p}(t),t\in[0,1]$ gaussian processes. Can we claim that
$g_{i}$ is independent of $g_{j}$ given all the remaining processes if and only if
$\text{cov}(g_{i}(s),g_{j}(t)\,|\,g_{k},k\ne i,j)=0$ for all $s,t\in[0,1]$?

Comment: You probably need a joint Gaussia-ness assumption. Marginally gaussian + uncorrelated does not imply independence.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390722 for  a vaguely related question.

Comment: I probably shoud have added that they follow jointly a p-dimensional Gaussian process. I was a little bit hesitant about that since I couldn't find anything online about joint gaussian processes.